# Drupal taxonomy multi-select default value

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, selectlist, multi-select

I'm using drupal 6.16 and have a set of taxonomy terms that are set up as a multi-select box.  I would like for the first item to be selected when the user loads the page.  I dont know if I need to add code to a file or just simply change a setting. I should warn you I do not have a lot of experience, but would rate myself as a low intermediate level programmer.

Thanks in advance
msindle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Taxonomy Defaults](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_defaults) module looks just the ticket. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Taxonomy Defaults allows you to assign default terms from any vocabulary to any node-type. The default terms will be pre-selected on the /node/add form, but can be edited.
>
> If a vocabulary is marked as "Hidden" for a particular content type, then that vocabulary will not be shown on the /node/add form and the default terms will be assigned automatically and cannot be edited.

Comment: That looks like it might work...I'll give it a try!  
Thanks lazysoundsystem!